# What is the reason for weighing a slice of fish?

Tags: fish

I got a question in my class and that was,'What is the reason for weighing a slice of fish?' Please help me out before my exams. On other sites it tells me that why should you weight fish before and after cooking. The question does not say before cooking or after cooking. It does not even tell what the fish slice for. Please help me understand before my exams. Thankyou

Comment: There must be more context or background to this question.

Comment: What are you studying? The answer could be culinary (knowing how to make it taste good), nutritional (knowing what your body will "get" from the piece of food), economic (knowing what to charge for the fish)...it goes on and on. More context is necessary.

Comment: I agree that it isn't possible to give a good answer with so few information. I am putting the question on hold, if you edit it to have enough information, we will reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Without other context or information, there cannot be a definitive answer.

The most common reason in professional food service would be to ensure uniform portion control.